# Trying to apply logic to pull certain rows based on results in the where

Tags: sql-server-2012, logic, where-clause

I have a query that, in a perfect world,  would pull, for example...

If Bill has 3 rows of data:

- Pending
- Pending
- Active

I'm trying to apply logic where if a patient has an Active status I'd just want that row to display:
Active

But if Sara has 3 rows:

- Pending
- Pending
- Pending

I'd want all 3 Pendings to show.  Only if the patient has an Active will just the Active show

```
select distinct
        MRN
      ,[RX Number]
      ,[Status]

where Status = case when d.Status = 'ACTIVE' then Status 
                    when d.Status <> 'ACTIVE' then Status  end
```

Right now my results are pulling (for the Bill example above)

- Pending
- Pending
- Active

Instead of

- Active

Answer (score 0):

You could use `EXISTS`:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT [Status] FROM [dbo].[Table1] WHERE [Status] = 'ACTIVE' AND [Patient] = 'Bill')
    SELECT DISTINCT MRN, [RX Number], [Status]
    FROM [dbo].[Table1]
    WHERE [Patient] = 'Bill'
        AND [Status] = 'ACTIVE'
ELSE
    SELECT DISTINCT MRN, [RX Number], [Status]
    FROM [dbo].[Table1]
    WHERE [Patient] = 'Bill'
```

Comment: So 'If Exists' can start a query?  I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: then something must be wrong with your query, post an update to your post with your query so we can take a look.

Comment: I surely can. It’s a large query though. Roughly 1,000 lines. It’s multiple CTEs and then I applied your logic to the select after the CTEs

Comment: Surely you dont need to post 1000 lines to reproduce the error.